# Развертка проекта Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Существуют ли быстрые способы развертки yii2 advanced на хостинге, после того как сайт был сделан на локальном сервере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего запустить перенос проекта через git или другую CVS.
При инициализации проекта в зависимости от окружения (production / development) устанавливаются или нет только разработческие модули (тот же gii) которых на публичном сервере не должно быть ни под каким видом.
Ну и composer-ские расширения лучше ставить через composer.

Получается, что в идеальном случае процесс выглядит так:

1. Выгрузить изменения через git (все таблицы в базе конечно же делались через миграции...)
2. Сделать дамп данных (если необходимо)
3. Перейти на хостинг, установить приложение из репозитория
4. Composer install
5. Инициализация (prod)
6. Настройка конфига на подключение к БД Миграции
7. Импорт данных в БД (если необходимо)

Answer (score 1):

Перенести приложение и откорректировать входной скрипт, если нужно

Comment: Каким образом можно использовать консольные команды на внешнем сервере? (что бы env=Production прописать)

Comment: Это надо сделать на локальном сервере, а потом уже переместить на хостинг. При этом не забудьте о входном скрипте, насколько помню у Advanced он лежит в подкаталоге. У хостингов обычно один каталог для входного файла "public_html" к примеру.

Comment: Смотря что за хостинг, и что за приложение вообще. Если хостер дает доступ к SSH, то пользуйтесь им для консольных команд, если нужно.
Так же тоже зависит от того, что именно вы хотите получить: приложение и веб в одной директории, разбивать фронтэнд и бэкенд на разные домены, или модулями...